# Can I create a POJO in file A, and require it file B, to create a new object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js to do a little bit of scripting. In file A, I have an object definition like this

```
class Thing {
  constructor() {
      this.x = 42;
      this.y = 3.14;
  }

  f() {}
  g() {}
}
```

Then in file B, I have this:

```
var Thing = require('./Thing.js');
console.log(new Thing());
```

The result is a TypeError: Thing is not a constructor.

Maybe I'm too fresh out of Java, but I was hoping that I could keep a folder full of objects that I expect to use commonly for a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss to export the Thing class in Thing.js

```
module.exports = Thing
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly export your class.